# Only Date is saved and not time in sql Database from C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm having an issue with saving the time into my SQL database.

The system should save time and date to the database when the user scans into the building. At the current moment it saves date but time is saved as  00:00.

I had problems converting the date to SQL during the save process, so maybe i've made a mistake in the process. I've looked at it for ages and cant see why it wouldnt save the time as well.

Any ideas? here is the code in question

```
  var currentdate = DateTime.Now;
                    var TimeAccess = currentdate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                    com.Connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineering);
                    com.Connection.Open();

                    com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AccessHistory (DoorID,UserID,TimeAccess,Status) VALUES (@DoorID,@UserID,@TimeAccess,@Status)";

                    com.Parameters.Add("@DoorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DoorNumber;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboUserID.Text;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@TimeAccess", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TimeAccess;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Successful";
```

Thank you

Comment: Can't you use GetDate function in SQL instead of sending it from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not to change its datatype and convert it to `string`, just pass it directly to the database if you have column in database of type `date` or `datetime`:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@TimeAccess", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = currentDate;
```

Comment: thank you this worked! i tried something earlier to this but i had DateTime2 instead of DateTime, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `DateTime` instead of `Date` in 2nd line:

```
var TimeAccess = currentdate.DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: This actually is the bug, but the whoöle conversion to string should go away

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass `DateTime.Now` for command parameters and make sure database column is `DateTime`. That's It.

```
 com.Parameters.Add("@TimeAccess", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

You can remove below from your code as It is not required at all.

```
  var currentdate = DateTime.Now;
  var TimeAccess = currentdate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                com.Connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineering);
                com.Connection.Open();

                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AccessHistory (DoorID,UserID,TimeAccess,Status) VALUES (@DoorID,@UserID,getdate(),@Status)";

                com.Parameters.Add("@DoorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DoorNumber;
                com.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboUserID.Text;
               com.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Successful";
```

Use Getdate()